# Permissions in Excel

Tags: vba, permissions

I have a sheet in Excel that has permissions set up to "Allow Users to Edit Ranges".

These different ranges consist of columns that users with different permissions can edit.

Is there any way to exclude cells/rows from these ranges?

For instance, I want to say I want the range of everything in column A except when cells in in column G of that row have nothing in them.

Alternatively, is there any way to use Macros to print out these complicated ranges?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the cells with vba or manually and set the locked property to false before locking the sheet. This will allow the user to edit those range/cells.

[image]

You can use conditional formatting to identify these locked cells.

Select your range (ctrl-A for all the cells).
Conditional formatting
formula is:  `=CELL("protect",A1)=0`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Allow Users to Edit Ranges" only allows us to specify the range(s), not to apply a rule that would allow, or disallow, editing.

You could use `Data Validation` to produce an error message. For example, creating a **Custom** validation rule of

```
=K2<>""
```

in a particular cell would mean that an error message will be produced if they attempt to put a value into this other cell if K2 is empty. You need to uncheck the box which says `Ignore Blank`.

This is not foolproof though, as a Copy/Paste would wipe-out the rule.

It can be done with VBA, but even then it could be circumvented with Copy/Paste. However, the (for example) `BeforeSave` event could be used to check the content of these cells and produce a message and prevent the save.

Disclaimer: I don't know whether VBA works with a file that uses the "Allow Users to Edit Ranges" feature.